# To identify if form has any elements

Tags: jquery, html

How do identify if the form has DIV or not ?

Empty form

```
<form id="savedSearchesForm" method="get"> </form>
```

Form with Div

```
<form id="savedSearchesForm" method="get"> 
<div> 1</div>
<div> 2</div>
</form>
```

based on this am trying to perform some operation. I tried with Jquery .length but not working as expected ?

Any easy ways will help

Comment: `.length` [is working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3fk2r/1/) so you didn't try it properly.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method to discover the presence of `div` element within the form:

```
$('form div').length;
```

Or:

```
$('form').find('div').length;
```

Or, more specifically for your case:

```
$('#savedSearchesForm div').length;
```

Any of these could be combined with an assessment, such as:

```
$('#savedSearchesForm div').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.children()`

```
$("#savedSearchesForm").children().length;

<form id="savedSearchesForm" method="get"> 
    <div> 1</div>
    <div> 2</div>
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ja7Pv/

Output: 2

Edit: This will only count the direct children of the form. If there are children within these, they will not be counted.

Comment: the problem with children() is if there is a div inside a div, this won't be counted. Children() only obtain directly children

Comment: @MichaelAguilar -- Very true, ill edit the post to include this, always nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
$('#savedSearchesForm').find('div').length
```